# Class and Interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a interface Named `IMyInterface` it contains four methods `method1`,`method2`,`method3`,`method4` and we are having 2 classes named as `Base class` and `derived class`, you have to implement `method1`,`method2` in base class and `method3`,`method4` in derived class.

How is it possible can any one help me

Comment: what about use `abstract class` instead of `interface` ?

Comment: Looks like interview question or homework. The answer is not possible BTW.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually pretty simple, you should declare the base class as abstract and mark Method3 and Method4 abstract in it and then implement them in the derived class. Here's a sample implementation:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
    void Method3();
    void Method4();
}

abstract class BaseClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void Method1()
    {
    }
    public void Method2()
    {
    }

    public abstract void Method3();
    public abstract void Method4();
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Method3()
    {
    }
    public override void Method4()
    {
    }
}
```